# What are some alternatives to PlayN?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, playn

I would like to know what alternatives are out there before making a decision on which to use, thanks. Possibly one that supports both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to develop in C#, the **[MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame)** (an open source port of [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)) framework works with [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) (iOS) and [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) (Android). As a bonus, it works on XBOX and has recently been made to work with Google Chrome's [native client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/).

If you want to develop in C or C++ you can use **[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/index.php)**, which has been made to work on both iOS and Android.

**[libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)** is a Java Android game development library for which there is [active effort currently underway](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/LibgdxForIOS) to get it running on iOS using the [Avian VM](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/index.html).

**[cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)** is an iOS game development library for which there's a[port for Android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/), though cocos2d is an Objective-C API and cocos2d-android is a Java API, so you can't share code between them directly.

There are undoubtedly others if you want to dig deeper or have a higher tolerance for experimental code.