# Alternatives to playN

Tags: game-engine, playn

i want to create games for multiple platforms. I want to code my games one against a common API/framework and the framework could compile the game for multiple platforms. I want the game to work as an HTML game in all browsers and also can be complied as a native app for android, iOS.

Based on these requirements i landed up on playN and currently exploring its capabilities but really stuck because of poor documentation and tutorials. though the implemented samples do help.

is there any other such frameworks probably more mature than playN with the above said capabilities.

thanks, responses much appreciated.

Comment: Would libGDX fit your use case? (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

Comment: seems interesting this also requires GWT. thanks for replying i will take a look at libGDX.

Answer (score 2):

[libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx) is a Java solution, although the [What are some alternatives to PlayN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862013/what-are-some-alternatives-to-playn) page shows other alternatives too.
This post compares PlayN and libGDX: [libgdx or playn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962138/libgdx-or-playn)